# I want to add border radius in stack graph in high charts for some particular data

Tags: highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYOVT.png) See in the example, when I don't have blue data then border-radius should come on black part in the last case. How I can achieve that??

Add border radius on black part if blue is hidden

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that setting a *borderRadius* for a single point is not possible according to Highchart's API. You can only set a *borderRadius* for the whole series. Splitting your points into several series would work, but I'm not sure if the whole demo still makes sense.

API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.borderRadius